# Is there a function or such in VBA to find distinct values in a range?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a function or such thing in VBA to find distinct values in a range ?

Otherwise i guess I'll just write a Sub using a Collection, but that sounds a little overkill. I am never a big fan of browsing cells in a range. That seems to get things slower.

Comment: Can you use this: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$13").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo ?

Comment: +1 for being against cell iteration, you could still use a function that uses an advanced filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past is to use a worksheet to manipulate the data using the in-built functionality of Excel (rather than VBA specifically).

Record a macro whilst selecting a list of values in a worksheet column, then use the Advanced Filter functionality to 'Copy to Another Location' whilst the 'Unique records only' checkbox is checked.

This will give you a unique list in the destination column, from which you can read the values in VBA and continue what you were doing.

Don't forget to edit out the 'fluff' that recording a macro will inevitably write in for you.

Comment: where do I find this Advanced Filter thing ?

Comment: Depending on your version, it'll either be `Data -> Filter -> Advanced Filter...` in menus up to Excel 2003, or you'll see a button with a funnel icon on the `Data` section of the Ribbon in more recent versions.